# Why is a syscall from inline assembly executed twice when called directly from println, but not when stored in a temporary variable?

Tags: rust, system-calls, interrupt

I have the following function which triggers a syscall in my OS to print a string to the screen:

```
pub fn print(ptr: *const u8, len: usize) -> u32 {
    let r: u32;
    unsafe {
        asm!("int 0x80" : "={eax}"(r) : "{eax}"(1u32), "{esi}"(ptr as u32), "{ecx}"(len as u32) : : "intel");
    }
    r
}
```

However, when I execute it as follows:

```
const s: &'static str = "Hello, World!\n";
println!("{}", print(s.as_ptr(), s.len()));
```

I get the following output:

```
Hello, World!
Hello, World!
0
```

But, when I write this:

```
const s: &'static str = "Hello, World!\n";
let r = print(s.as_ptr(), s.len());
println!("{}", r);
```

It correctly prints:

```
Hello, World!
0
```

Looking at this in [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/mmjeHs), I can see that there is only one `int` instruction that would be triggering the syscall, and as far as I can tell, the `print` function is only called once. I've never experienced side-effects occurring twice in Rust before. Does anyone know what is causing this strange behaviour?

Comment: Your code is weird, `sys_write` is number `1` in x64, but `4` in x32, so since your `eax=1` I'm guessing you are in x64 mode, but then you're using 32-bit registers! Moreover, the `fd` argument, that I'm guessing you want it to be `1 (stdout)` should be passed in some register too.

Comment: ... but your Godbolt link is 32-bits, but in 32-bit Linux, syscall number 1 is `sys_exit`.

Comment: @rodrigo This isn't Linux. I'm writing my own basic OS, and for now I only have one syscall (print) with number 1. Everything is in 32-bit because I've decided to develop for protected mode not long mode. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Ahhh, that explains the lacking of OS tag. Anyway I've tested the proper code in Linux and both versions print just one line, as expected. I'm guessing this is not a Rust issue, but maybe there is a bug in your OS.

Comment: @rodrigo Damn :/ I've had a look but I can't find a bug. I guess it goes into the long list of weird kernel bugs I can't explain.. thanks for the help though. For the record, which version of the compiler were you using?

Comment: I used `rustc 1.40 nightly`, to be able to use the `asm!`. On second thought maybe your bug is in the implementation of the `std` module?